# How to set up a HorizontalScrollView in Android?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, horizontalscrollview

I'm new to android but I've done the notepad tutorial. Now I'm trying to write my own layout. The eventual layout will be like this on one page:

1st row: [ ------search bar----- ] [ button ]

2nd row: [ text-tab ] [ text-tab ] [ text-tab ] <-- click on one of these to change 3rd row content

3rd row: [ content to fill rest of height ]

... and when the user scrolls the page left or right another layout/page is shown.

So I started off using Eclipse's graphical editor for a new android XML layout file.
I dragged a text-box onto the canvas, then I increased the width as in the diagram above.
Then I added the button at the end of it, so that the first row was complete.

Now when I try to add anything below it doesn't work. So I switched to XML view. I copied and pasted the LinearLayout so that I could edit it to make the 2nd row.

Now I get the error: HorizontalScrollView can host only one direct child

Okay, so I understand the Horizontal Scroll View should only contain 1 LinearLayout but then what is the correct structure to set up this layout?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="1130dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp">
        <requestFocus/>
    </EditText>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="152dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text="Button"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="1130dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp">
        <requestFocus/>
    </EditText>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="152dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text="Button"/>
</LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="1130dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp">
        <requestFocus/>
    </EditText>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="152dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text="Button"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="1130dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp">
        <requestFocus/>
    </EditText>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="152dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:text="Button"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: ohhh so you just wrap the whole thing under another LinearLayout... thanks!

Comment: After wrapping those two LinearLayouts under a vertical-oriented one, the two horizontal ones appear on the same line, one after the other. How do I make the the second one appear on another row?

Comment: There was a typo, where it says orientation='vertical' it should have been android:orientation='vertical'. Problem solved thanks.